# How to know what internal process runs an application

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am developing an Android application, which hosts two processes, as declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file through the "android:process" XML attributes :

1. a first main process stated on the  XML node with a value set to "dummy.com" ;
2. a background service, declared as a  XML node with a value set to ":service".

Every time one of those processes start, my "onCreate()" method of the overridden application that I have declared in the manifest is invoked. My question is:

is there a way to know what causes this method to be invoked? Is the "Application::onCreate()" method invoked due to the start-up of the main process, is it due to the service process?

Since I have named to the two processes differently, I suppose that there is a way to access to that information at runtime, but I could not find a way.

Thank for your time. Regards,
Édouard

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if your application or activity was started by "dummy.com" or ".service"?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Application.getApplicationInfo()` which returns an Object that contains the process name which should tell you whether it was invoked because process1 or process2 was started.

Comment: No, sorry, the ApplicationInfo only returns the "android:process" attribute declared on the "application" top XML node, not the actual process name.

Comment: I'm so sad that no Android guru can answer my question. Maybe what I intend to achieved is not feasible: anyone?

Comment: I'm going to post that request on the Android forum, maybe I will be more lucky...